Print only endnotes in Beamer
I wonder whether there is any way to print endnotes (or footnotes) in Beamer? I understand that \notes could be an option but the problem is that it does not provide numbered endnotes. \printendnotes, on the other hand, also prints the main body, which I do not want. Below is a MWE:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{enotez}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\textbf{Slide title}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Some texts\endnote{Some texts for endnote}
    \item More texts\endnote{More texts for endnote}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\printendnotes
\end{document}


Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem and shows what you've tried. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}.

If you've previously compiled the whole presentation, then you can temporarily use \setbeameroption{show only notes} to hide the normal frames (don't make changes to the notes while you do that, they won't get updated):
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeameroption{show only notes}
\usepackage{enotez}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Slide title}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Some texts\endnote{Some texts for endnote}
    \item More texts\endnote{More texts for endnote}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\printendnotes
\end{document}



This looks like a good solution. Thanks a lot @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz.
